# How to use Steam Networking Sockets with Facepunch.Steamworks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, steam, steamworks-api

I've been using [Facepunch](https://github.com/Facepunch/Facepunch.Steamworks) for Steam Networking for my game. I'm familiar with the P2P Solution that Facepunch provides, but Steam P2P is obsolete and has been replaced with Sockets. However, I can't for the life of me find any useful documentation/tutorials/etc. that will help me get started with Sockets, and the [Creating a Socket Server](https://wiki.facepunch.com/steamworks/Creating_A_Socket_Server) section on the wiki is very confusing. How do I use Steam Networking Sockets with Facepunch.Steamworks **WITHOUT transports** (Like Facepunch transport for Netcode)?